# Is it possible to connect zookeeper and kafka via SASL , kafka broker and its clients via SSL without enabling plain text?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am using Kafka Version 0.10.1. I connected Kafka brokers and its clients via SSL and its working fine.Now I have a query with some limitations.
My limitations are

1. No Plain text communications allowed
2. The connection between Kafka-brokers and its clients be SSL.
3. The connection between Kafka-brokers and zookeeper via SASL (since zookeeper doesn't support SSL).

Since all inter-broker communications are set to SSL. I have a query that, Whether SASL connection between Zookeeper and Kafka-Broker is possible without enabling plaintext in Kafka-Broker.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to setup a Kafka cluster with Zookeeper with all the requirements you listed.

You'll need to have 2 listeners `SSL` and `SASL_SSL` (No `PLAINTEXT`) in your Kafka config:

```
listeners=SASL_SSL://host.name:port,SSL://host.name:port
```

Set inter broker to `SSL`

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
```

I suggest you check the Security section in the Kafka documentation to see what you need to do exactly to get this working, including how to configure clients so they connect over `SASL_SSL`: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security

It also contains a section about securing Zookeeper:
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#zk_authz

Comment: Here 'SASL_SSL' means SASL connection only or SASL connection with SSL.

Comment: And one more . So I need to configure for  both SASL and SSL connection in Kafka broker ?

Comment: `SASL_SSL` means SASL over an SSL connection. `SASL_PLAINTEXT` also exists but it is for plaintext connections so not secured.

Yes you'll need to configure both SASL and SSL.